# QGraphicsSceneTextItem delete old text

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

What I want to do is to delete or update the text value of the `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` that i added to a `QGraphicsItem`,but for a certain cause the text do not update but it's acumulated in the item created.this is what i have done for now :

```
void DiagramItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event )
{
    if (event->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    Dialog *mydiag = new Dialog();
    mydiag->show();
    if(mydiag->exec())
    {
        QString tx = mydiag->getname();
        txt = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
        txt->setText(tx);
        txt->setParentItem(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating new text item every time. You need to keep a pointer to added text item and use it to update text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to eliminate two rows from your code:

```
QString tx = mydiag->getname();
// txt = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
txt->setText(tx);
// txt->setParentItem(this);
```

So you won't create new items all the time.

But after this you can remove one more line:

```
// QString tx = mydiag->getname();
// txt = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
txt->setText( mydiag->getname() );
// txt->setParentItem(this);
```

Do you initialize the txt in class constructor ? If yes than the previous code will be okay, but if you don't than you may want to use this:

```
if ( txt == nullptr )
{
    QString tx = mydiag->getname();
    txt = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem;
    txt->setText(tx);
    // txt->setParentItem(this);
}
```